# Displaying Median Rent Change YoY from 2021-2022 by Manhattan Neighborhood

Tags: visualization, median, tableau-desktop, manhattan

I have been playing around with the Tableau Map functions and just noticed it was a built-in background layer displaying neighborhoods of the NYC boroughs. I got the idea of showing the YoY median percent change in rent by the Manhattan neighborhood. However, when I upload an excel file to Tableau, it doesn't recognize the neighborhoods as they are background layers. I've seen other visuals of breakdowns by the Manhattan neighborhood, so I know it's possible.

The excel file I imported contained Inward, Hudson Heights, Washington Heights & Manhattanville. Tableau is reading them as null values and won't give me the option to decide what they are.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So, 2 months later and I end up getting a project to work on from a possible employer and a file they send me is sale prices by Manhattan neighborhood. I was able to create a filled map showing the median sale price by neighborhood. I had to find the geospatial data to import into Tableau (which I will provide below). Next was adding zip codes for each neighborhood. I know there are multiple zip codes per neighborhood and it changes depending on the website, but I used Zillow as guidance. Finally after the geospatial file and neighborhood file were imported into Tableau, I blended them on the zip code data. Pretty cool how I ended up being able to answer my own question 2 months later. Below is what the map looks like.

NYC Geospatial Data: https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Business/Zip-Code-Boundaries/i8iw-xf4u/data?no_mobile=true

[image]